# how to test in-app purchases after an apk is published

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, apk, publish

So we've published our first app v1.0 and we are preparing for v1.1. To do so I need to test purchases against this up but uploading the new (test) apk creates 2 problems:
1. if the new apk v1.1 is activated to test it, it will stomp the older release apk
2. the new (test) apk needs to be active to test purchases against it

Currently we created another app called "Test App" where we'll upload our QA test versions to in order to test in-app purchases.

What is the best practice for testing updates etc.?